# Will PHP not write hashed password to a file?

Tags: php

I am currently trying to test PHP's password verification, and doing so using the following code:

HTML file:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" id="set">
    <label>Set</label>
    <input name="password1" id="password1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Add password">
</form>
<form action="check.php" id="check">
    <label>Check</label>
    <input name="password2" id="password2">
    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Test Password">
</form>
```

PHP add password to file:

```
<?php
    $password = $_POST['password1'];
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $file = 'hash.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, $hashed_password, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

PHP compare inputted password with the one in the file:

```
<?php
    $password = $_POST['password2'];
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
        echo 'Correct';
    }
    echo 'Wrong';
?>
```

I know storing passwords to a file isn't the smartest idea, but this is just to test.

So what I am trying to do is input the password in the first form, hit submit and it store the hashed password to `hash.txt` and then when I re-input the password in the second field it should hopefully echo 'Correct'.

The issue I am having is when I press submit, on the first form, it sends me to `post.php`, and doesn't add the hashed password to `hash.txt`

Comment: You didn't read the password back from the file in the second script!!!

Comment: Is the file writeable ?

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting and/or looked at your error logs?

Comment: what if you write out the full path here `$file = 'hash.txt';`? From `/` (root) to your folder.

Comment: Sidenote: Any special reason for your using a text file, rather than a database? Handling files are a lot of work.

Comment: and is the folder writeable also?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't even get to the point in running the second script as the first one doesn't complete

Comment: So add the error reporting to the first script as well and see if that tells you something

Comment: @Daan Yes it is, so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's just to test, no reason not to use a database, I just don't have one set up yet, so the txt file was an easy test

Comment: You should probably `Loose` the `FILE_APPEND` it does no harm, but there is no way this code could cope with more than on Hash in that file See amended answer

Comment: @jordsta95 So, is the question solved? Did you try Riggs' answer?

Comment: Are we sure OP is not trying to read/write from/to a file in `/` (root)?

Comment: It is in the root, sorry I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Check.php` needs to read the password from the file you saved it in to be able to check it.

Also an `if then else` would be better for outputting your message otherwise you will always get the `echo 'Wrong';` message regardless

This would probably have been quite obvious if you had turned on error reporting in this script. I assume you are working on a LIVE server so they would be turned off by default.

`post.php` Add some error reporting and remove FILE_APPEND as there is no way this code could cope with more than one hash being stored in that file. Maybe thats one of your problems!

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $password = $_POST['password1'];
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $file = 'hash.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, $hashed_password);
?>
```

`Check.php`

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$password = $_POST['password2'];

$hashed_password= file_get_contents('hash.txt');

if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
    echo 'Correct';    
} else {
    echo 'Wrong';
}
?>
```